# Class 'GlobalSetting' not found in ( sfPropelRoute.class.php )

Tags: php, symfony1

I clone a project from github to localhost and configure it on localhost by adding these files according to localhost setting.

```
project/config/databases.yml
project/config/projectConfigration.class.php
projec/config/app.yml
projec/apps/b2c/config/app.yml
projec/web/connection.php
```

but it is displaying this error message.

**Fatal error: Class 'GlobalSetting' not found in E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\PEAR\symfony\plugins\sfPropelPlugin\lib\routing\sfPropelRoute.class.php on line 41**

I am using symfony version 1.2.12.

Note: I am new in symfony and github, I already post a question related this but not get any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I comment this code in `project/apps/backend/config/routing.yml` now its working without any error.

```
global_setting:
  class: sfPropelRouteCollection
  options:
    model:                GlobalSetting
    module:               global_setting
    prefix_path:          global_setting
    column:               id
    with_wildcard_routes: true
```